# Adding a foreach inside of an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I want to add a dynamic array inside of another array, here's my array :

```
$myarray = array(
        'options' => array( ),
    );
```

And here's the dynamic array :

```
$page = array(
array('id' => '1' ,'title'=>'Page1' ),
array('id' => '2' ,'title'=>'Page2' )
);
```

I want to `$myarray` to be like this :

```
$myarray = array(
        'options' => 
            array('1' => 'Page1' ,'2'=>'Page2' ),
);
```

Here's what I tried :

```
 foreach ($page as $key => $value) {
   $myarray['options'][]=array(
   "".$value['id']."" =>"".$value['title'].""
   );
}
```

Any help with this? Thanks. 
 
Here's [**a codepad demo**](http://codepad.org/olAKciiQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$myarray = [];

foreach($page as $key => $value) {
    $myarray['options'][$value['id']] = $value['title'];
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. ;) Please accept it so anyone who wants to learn can see my answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$myarray['options'] = array_reduce($page, function($options, $item){
    $options[$item['id']] = $item['title'];
    return $options;
});
```